# Find characters that match a regex's set

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex `w_p[a-z]`

It would match input like `w_pa, w_pb ... w_pz`. I like to find which character exactly was matched i.e. `a,b or z` for the above input. Is this possible with java regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to capture:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("w_p([a-z])");

final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
if (m.find())
    // what is matched is in m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use Regexpr groups. `w_p([a-z])` defines a group for the character you are looking for.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("w_p([a-z])");

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String character = matcher.group(1)
}
```

matcher.group(0) contains all that was matched (w_pa or w_pb etc.)

matcher.group(1) contains what was found in the first () pair.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The REGEX will be something like this:
    w_p([a-z])
So you will create a group from wich you can get the value